# Alternatives to MySQL that do not have a GPL licence

Tags: mysql, windows, postgresql, solaris, sybase

We have a built a new data fusion C++ algorithm which uses SQLite as an internal database.
However, we would like each of the multiple C++ threads to do a parallel db write and SQLite cannot do that.

So we are now looking at MySQL which allows each of the multiple C++ threads to do a parallel db write.
However, the MySQL non-GPL licence is too costly and we don't want to rely on Oracle for MySQL support since our data fusion C++ algorithm will soon have a US patent.

Are they are any alternatives to MySQL which allows each of the multiple C++ threads to do a parallel relational database write which do not have a costly licensing policy like ORACLE MySQL?

So far, I am starting to look at PostgreSQL's BSD license and Sybase open source relational database.

Could someone tell us if PostgreSQL or SYbase is the right direction to go in?

Comment: So you want to *distribute* mySQL along with your product?

Comment: Pekka, Thank you for yor reply. Our CTO does not want to distribute mySQL with our soon to be USA patented data fusion product since the Oracle GPL is too costly and we would have to tell Oracle about the details of our proprietary algorithm evrytime we had a technical question. That is why we are considering using Postgrel BSD and Sybase Open Source. Thank you.

Comment: @Frank, you seem confused. If you use MySQL, and destribute it you do not need to specify the sourcecode of your app that uses MySQL, only when you `create a derivitive work` based on MySQL. Oh and thank you's and good morning etc are considered fluff on SO. Thanks is appreciated when someone come up with a particularly wonderfull answer, otherwise keep it short and snappy :-)

Comment: @Johan, Thank you for your reply. Our main concern is the cost of Oracle GPL and Oracle technical support for commercial products. ALso, we don't whether Oracle will divest itself of MySQL since in a sense MySQL cannibalizes the sales of Oracle proprietary database products.

Comment: @Frank, polite as it may seem, please don't do `Thank you for your reply.` on every post. I understand your point. I would warmly recommend postgreSQL. it's a very good database.

Comment: Johan, MySQL AB's (and hence Oracle's) interpretation of the GPL as applied to the MySQL connect libs is that anything that uses the mysql connection libs is either GPL or subject to commercial licensing.  So if your app links to the mysql connection libs, it needs to either be sold with a commercial mysql license or be gpl licensed itself.  There are exceptions for some scripting langauges like PHP.  And personally I think MySQL AB / Oracle would lose a court case claiming the linking would do what they say it would.  But I don't have to find out, I use pgsql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be quite a few options. If you're not worried about being cross platform, you could try SQL Server Express. You can use this in production subject to some limitations (I think the limit relates to the type of hardware you can install it on). There is also an express edition of Oracle with similar usage constraints.

In the open source world, there is Firebird which I believe you should be able to use in embedded mode (that is, without having to install a separate network server process). I haven't used this in production but it has been around for many years and looking through SO, it seems to be well regarded. It uses MPL so there should be no licensing risks.

For completeness, you could consider MaxDB from SAP and the Ingres Database System. MaxDB seems to be a very capable DBMS but when I tried it years ago (version 7.6) it seemed to be extrodinarily difficult to work with. I've never worked with (or heard of anyone working with) Ingres but apparently it's open source and can be freely used.

Like "a_horse_with_no_name", I'm not aware of there being an open source edition of Sybase although I might have just missed it.

Phil

Comment: We will definitely look at Firebird and possibly Ingres based on your suggestions. We have a cross platform customer base (60% Windows , 40% UNIX/Linux) so we can't use Microsft SQL Server Express. SAP is our major competitor so I thibk my managers won't want use any SAP products. I am accepting your answer.

Answer (score 3):

PostgreSQL is definitely a very good alternative to MySQL.

In my opinion PostgreSQL is actually the better choice anyway looking at all the things that MySQL doesn't get right and the number of SQL features that they still don't have.

But again that's my personal opinion.

In terms of licensing the Postgres license is indeed more flexible for commercial usage than the GPL.

The support from the PostgreSQL community on the mailing list is outstanding - I don't know if there is something comparable in the Sybase world (actually I didn't know that Sybase is now OpenSource).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I just found that Postgres SQL Server allows parallel write per ecah thread/database connection. That is great news because it speeds up our application for large potential data fusion customers by 40 to 50%. However, I also read the PostGres SQL Server cannot be embedded with the POstsql client in a binary DLL/SO? Is that true? If so, how can we reduce the number of DLL/SO's(ideally 1) that we distribute to the potential customer. Thank you for your help.

Comment: **Any** serious DBMS will allow parallel writes from multiple connections. That's what they are meant for. And no PostgreSQL (not *PostGres*) was never designed to run as "embedded".

Comment: Postgres is a perfectly acceptable name.  As is PostgreSQL, or pgsql.  Postgre, however, is not.